# Jtable cell selection and highlighting

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an attached code, it working but with a little issue. I'm able to highlight a cell with blue color. What I want is after highlighting a single cell with a blue color I want to be able to un-highlight the same cell by clicking it again. For example when I highlight cell 1, it will be highlighted with blue but when I click it again it won't be un-highlighted  unless I click another cell then click cell 1 again.

How can I fix this problem.

In the code I'm only testing cell 1 to 4.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class myJTable extends JFrame {

    Container container;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane pane;
   
    static String oneSelected = "";
    static String twoSelected = "";
    static String threeSelected = "";
    static String fourSelected = "";
   
    int oneCount = 0;
    int twoCount = 0;
    int threeCount = 0;
    int fourCount = 0;
   
    public myJTable() {

        container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        String[] columnNames = {"No.1","No.2", "No.3", "No.4"};
        Object[][] rowData = {{"1", "2", "3", "4"},
            {"5", "6", "7", "8"},
            {"9", "10", "11", "12"},
            {"13", "14", "15", "16"},
            {"17", "18", "19", "20"}};

        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setRowHeight(50);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableRenderer());
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        container.add(pane);
       
           table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        final JTable jTable= (JTable)e.getSource();
        final int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
        final int column = jTable.getSelectedColumn();
        final String cellValue = (String)jTable.getValueAt(row, column);
        //textfield.setText(valueInCell);
       
        if (cellValue.equals("1") && oneCount == 0) {
        oneSelected  = cellValue;
        oneCount++;
        System.out.println("cell value is " +oneSelected);
        System.out.println("one count is " +oneCount);
        }
        else if (cellValue.equals("1") && oneCount >= 1) {
        oneSelected  = "";
        oneCount = 0;
        System.out.println("cell value is " +oneSelected);
        System.out.println("one count is " +oneCount);
        }
       
            if (cellValue.equals("2") && twoCount == 0) {
          twoSelected  = cellValue;
          twoCount++;
          System.out.println("cell value is " +twoSelected);
        }
            else if (cellValue.equals("2") && twoCount >= 1) {
        twoSelected  = "";
        twoCount = 0;
        System.out.println("cell value is " +twoSelected);
        System.out.println("two count is " +twoCount);
        }
           
            if (cellValue.equals("3") && threeCount == 0) {
          threeSelected  = cellValue;
          threeCount++;
          System.out.println("cell value is " +threeSelected);
           }
            else if (cellValue.equals("3") && threeCount >= 1) {
        threeSelected  = "";
        threeCount = 0;
        System.out.println("cell value is " +threeSelected);
        System.out.println("three count is " +threeCount);
        }
           
            if (cellValue.equals("4") && fourCount == 0) {
         fourSelected  = cellValue;
         fourCount++;
         System.out.println("cell value is " +fourSelected);
           }
            else if (cellValue.equals("4") && fourCount >= 1) {
        fourSelected  = "";
        fourCount = 0;
        System.out.println("cell value is " +fourSelected);
        System.out.println("four count is " +fourCount);
        }
        }
        }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
        myJTable frame = new myJTable();
        frame.setTitle("JTable Example");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(700, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class TableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
   
    String oneSValue = myJTable.oneSelected;
    String twoSValue = myJTable.twoSelected;
    String threeSValue = myJTable.threeSelected;
    String fourSValue = myJTable.fourSelected;
       
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
       
        if (value.equals(oneSValue) || value.equals(twoSValue) || value.equals(threeSValue) || value.equals(fourSValue)) {
            c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
          }
        else {
        c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
       
        return c;
       
    }
}
```

**FIRST EDIT:**

*I've edited the code and used the boolean variable isSelected to print whether the cells boolean 2D array changes from false to true but does not change*

```
class TableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

boolean cells[][] = new boolean [4][4];


Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

if(isSelected) {
if(cells[0][0] == false) {
System.out.println("cell 0 0 is " + cells[0][0]);
cells[0][0] = true;
}
else if(cells[0][0] == true) {
System.out.println("cell 0 0 is " + cells[0][0]);
}
}

return c;
}
}
```

Comment: *when I highlight cell 1, it will be highlighted with blue but when I click it again it won't be un-highlighted unless I click another cell then click cell 1 again* - So Is the requirement that only one cell can be highlighted at a time?

Comment: I want to highlight cells one by one, then un-highlight each cell by clicking on it again. The problem is when I click a cell it is highlighted but when I click it again to un-highlight it, it won't be un-highlighted unless I click another cell. I do have a condition set within a mouse listener.

Comment: Keeping variable like "oneCount, twoCount..." is the wrong approach as this can get unmaintainable as the grid size increases. I would keep a 2D Array of boolean values to indicate whether a cell should be highlighted or not. A mouse pressed on the cell would toggle the value. The renderer would check the value do the the highlighting.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, can you please elaborate or give some example

Comment: In your renderer you keep a 2D Array to represent the state of each cell. You already have a MouseListener. You already know the row/column of the cell. So you then toggle the state of the cell in the renderer and invoke repaint() on the table.. You add code to the renderer to highlight the cell based on the state of the cell.

Comment: I initialized the 2D boolean array and it should be false by default. When I assign it to true I get the exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception"

boolean cells[][] = new boolean[row][column];
cells[row][column] = true;

How should I add it in a mouse listener and renderer?

Comment: In the constructor of your renderer you need to create the 2D Array based on the size of your table, which appears to be 4x4.  In your renderer you also need a method like "toggleCellHighlight(row, column). Now, in the MouseListener you invoke this method for the specific row/column. Also, you can't just set it to "true" because you also need the ability to reset it to "false" when you click on the cell again. Post a proper [mre] showing your attempt if you need more help.

Comment: I've edited the code and used the boolean variable isSelected to print whether the cells boolean 2D array changes from false to true but does not change so I can use the boolean on the change color method.

Comment: @camickr _In your renderer you keep a 2D Array to represent the state of each cell_ ehh .. no: I would argue that keeping table state is __not__ the task of a renderer, all it might do is compare it's own location with some state of the table and configure itself accordingly. Maybe misunderstanding both the requirement and and your comment, though :)

Comment: also unrelated: please keep the your tags focused .. uitableView is clearly documented to be about iOS ..

Comment: @kleopatra don't disagree that normally a renderer is generic and can be used by any table so it should not track state information. In this case we need custom data to track the highlight state of each cell. We then need the ability to toggle the state and finally render the state. I was thinking that it might be easier to have a single class handle this functionality, instead of having the logic split in multiple classes. In any case I made a simple example below which maybe you can improve upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below the "state" of the highlight is contained in a 2D Array that has been added as data to the table by using a "client property".

The MouseListener is used to toggle the highlighting state every time you click on a cell.

The renderer will then query the highlighting state in order to paint the background.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TableHighlight extends JPanel
{
    public TableHighlight()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTable table = new JTable(4, 4);
        add( new JScrollPane( table ) );

        boolean[][] highlights = new boolean[4][4];
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableRenderer());
        table.putClientProperty("highlights", highlights);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e)
            {
                JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int column = table.getSelectedColumn();

                boolean[][] highlights = (boolean[][])table.getClientProperty("highlights");
                highlights[row][column] = !highlights[row][column];

                table.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    private class TableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        boolean[][] highlights = (boolean[][])table.getClientProperty("highlights");
        boolean highlighted = highlights[row][column];

        if (highlighted)
            c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        else
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        return c;
    }
}

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableHighlight");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableHighlight());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Comment: as long as the state is not kept in the renderer, any solution is good (or bad) as the other - particularly as long as we (or me at least ;) can't be really certain that highlight != selected :)

Comment: Sorry to respond late. Thank you for the answer and everyone's contributions.